# Como conectar minha aplicação android a um banco de dados externo

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados, conexão

Tenho um site com algumas tabelas no banco de dados mysql.
O site já está conectado no banco de dados.

Tenho uma aplicação no Android Studio e gostaria de conectar a aplicação com o banco de dados externo (mysql no site). Sem ser o SQLITE. Como posso fazer essa conexão?
multiplataforma

Comment: Se não me engano tem uma duplicata disso em algum lugar mas não estou conseguindo achar. Bom, o recomendado nesse caso é sua aplicação Android não se conectar com o banco diretamente e sim chamar web services que acessam esse banco. Se você já tem um site conectado ao banco, poderia implementar web services nesse site para fazer essa comunicação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro de tudo, vc vai precisar de uma classe de conexão, eu utilizo essa em meus projetos com ajuda com php:

```
public class Conexao {

public static String postDados(String urlUsuario, String parametrosUsuario) {
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;

    try {

        url = new URL(urlUsuario);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Lenght", "" + Integer.toString(parametrosUsuario.getBytes().length));

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "pt-BR");

        connection.setUseCaches(false);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStreamWriter outPutStream = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream(), "utf-8");
        outPutStream.write(parametrosUsuario);
        outPutStream.flush();
        outPutStream.close();

        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "utf-8"));

        String linha;
        StringBuffer resposta = new StringBuffer();

        while((linha = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
         resposta.append(linha);
            resposta.append('\r');
        }

        bufferedReader.close();

        return resposta.toString();

    } catch (Exception erro) {

        return  null;
    } finally {

        if(connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Pronto, agora para usa-la você faz isso:

```
public class Main extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    String texto = "123";
    url = "url_do_seu_arquivo_php"; //Caso queira um get, só colocar na url
    //  ?variavel=valor

    //Parâmentros por post
    parametros = "texto=" + texto;

    new SolicitaDados().execute(url);

 }

 private class SolicitaDados extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected  String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        return Conexao.postDados(urls[0], parametros);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String resultado) {
        //String resultado tem o retorno


    }
 }
 }
```

Assim você envia os posts e gets para seu arquivo php, por exemplo, e lá o trata enviando o dado para o mysql, caso queira receber algo, na url você coloca o caminho com arquivo php e passa os paramentros necessários para este imprimir os dados, toda a resposta vem na String "resposta" no onPostExecute

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o Firebase para isso, além de banco de dados ele te oferece possibilidade de autenticação dos usuários, pushNotifications e diversas outras ferramentas, e além do mais ele tem um plano Free bem generoso, de modo que você não precisará gastar nada de início. Além de ser multiplataforma.

Answer (score -2):

MySql penso que não seja possível.
Ha uma ferramenta da google chamada FireBase Não é bem uma base de dados mas pode servir para o que você necessita.

Comment: Lógico que é possível

Comment: @WotonSampaio eu disse pensar nao ser possível estive ha tempos a tentar e não encontrei nenhuma forma de o fazer. Mas o PENSAR não ser possivel não significa que eu tenha razão